# Git pull no longer works when moving sd card from Raspberry Pi (1) to Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: git, raspberry-pi

I just got a new Raspberry Pi 3, and I moved my sd card from my old one (a Raspberry Pi 1) to it. It seems to run fine (using Raspbian Jessie), however when I try to run `git pull` for one of my projects it first doesn't do anything, and then gives an error after a few minutes:

```
Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I move the sd card back to the old pi it works again.

Does anyone know why this is? Is it not advised to move sd cards between raspberry pi's?

Edit: I noticed this is only broken when using WiFi on the Pi 3. When I use a cable it works fine.

Comment: Now that you've added the error... Are you connected to the network/internet? Can you contact github.com? If you're using SSH, can you `ssh git@github.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on the [raspberry pi forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=187331&p=1183118#p1183118) too, and there a solution came up.

[The answer by SurferTim](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1182304#p1182304) there states:

> To use ssh on wifi without ethernet: Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add
>   this to the end IPQoS 0 0
>
> edit: If you are using ssh as a client, you may need to add the same
>   to /etc/ssh/ssh_config

I edited both files, and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

This may be more appropriate for a comment but as I <s>don't</s> *didn't* have the rep I will post a few things you could try here:

Firstly it would be helpful if you could post the output error so we know what is wrong. Without any logs I can only guess.

- It might be a permission error. i.e the user doing the `git pull` does not have permission to write to the git directory.
- It could also be an issue with connecting to the internet.
- Maybe if you are pulling via SSH you don't have ssh access on the RPi3.
- Or it could be that you don't have the SSH key to access the repository because the keys aren't available or you don't have read access to the keys.

These are just a few of the possible causes of not being able to pull. In order to give more accurate help please post the error message and I will edit my answer.

Comment: I added the error to the original post ;) I also noticed there is only a problem when using WiFi, it works fine with a cable.